# I have questions on how to understand why my password generator is not executing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, password-generator

I'm a beginner programmer, so please forgive me if I'm not noticing the obvious.

I have run into problems with my password generator. First off, the code is not executing properly when I run the script, it prints "Your password is: ", and nothing else, the password won't generate.

I've checked the code with breakpoints, and nothing seems out of the ordinary. I'm just needing help to solve why it won't generate.

Once again, please forgive me if I'm not noticing the 'obvious'.

Thanks! And my code is shown below:

```py
import random

Characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Special_Characters = "~!@#$%^&*()_"
Numbers = "1234567890"
Chosen_Characters = []
Chosen_Special_Characters = []
Chosen_Numbers = []
Password = ""
Nums_amt = 0
S_Character_amt = 0
Character_amt = 0
Total_characters = Nums_amt + S_Character_amt + Character_amt

def Amount_of_Characters():
    num = random.randint(1, 9)
    return(num)

def Character_chooser(A_o_C, Char_amt, Char):
    global Chosen_Characters
    for i in range(A_o_C):
        Chosen_Characters += [random.choice(Char)]
        Char_amt += 1
    return(Chosen_Characters)

def Special_Character_chooser(A_o_C, S_Char_amt, S_Char):
    global Chosen_Special_Characters
    for i in range(A_o_C):
        Chosen_Special_Characters += [random.choice(S_Char)]
        S_Char_amt += 1
    return(Chosen_Special_Characters)

def Number_chooser(A_o_C, Num_amt, Num):
    global Chosen_Numbers
    for i in range(A_o_C):
        Chosen_Numbers += [random.choice(Num)]
        Num_amt += 1
    return(Chosen_Numbers)

def Assembler(A_o_C, C_c, S_C_c, N_c, Total_char, S_Char_amt, Char_amt, Num_amt, Pword):    
    one = random.shuffle(C_c)
    two = random.shuffle(S_C_c)
    three = random.shuffle(N_c)
    for i in range(Total_char):
        chooser = random.randint(1, 3)
        if i + 1 <= Char_amt:
            if chooser == 1:
                temp_num = random.randint(0, len(one))
                Pword += one[temp_num]
                two.pop(temp_num)
        if i + 1 <= S_Char_amt + Char_amt and i + 1 > Char_amt:
            if chooser == 1:
                temp_num = random.randint(0, len(two))
                Pword += two[temp_num]
                two.pop(temp_num)
        if i + 1 > S_Char_amt + Char_amt:
            if chooser == 1:
                temp_num = random.randint(0, len(three))
                Pword += three[temp_num]
                two.pop(temp_num)
    return(Pword)

A = Amount_of_Characters()
B = Character_chooser(Amount_of_Characters(), Character_amt, Characters)
C = Special_Character_chooser(Amount_of_Characters(), S_Character_amt, Special_Characters)
D = Number_chooser(Amount_of_Characters(), Nums_amt, Numbers)

print("Your password is: " + Assembler(A, B, C, D, Total_characters, S_Character_amt, Character_amt, Nums_amt, Password))
```

Comment: Just asking, why are you generating the password twice? You are first assigning values to `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. Right after that, you generate new values that aren't put to use.

Comment: I assigned them to the variables to shorten the 'Assembler' function, but I didn't know it also generated them, thanks you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: your code assumes that if you pass a variable into a function and change the value of the parameter, it changes the original. It doesn't. That and some other mistakes cause the program to fail.

Good programming style is not just a matter of looking good, it's about making your code easier to read for other programmers as well as your future self. So please allow me to comment on a few issues with your code:

- You named a function `Amount_of_Characters`, but you shouldn't used capital letters in function names in Python since those signify classes, instead name it `amount_of_characters`
- You then assign the function to result `A`, which doesn't really do anything, but a variable name should also be lowercase, name it `a`
- After doing this for four separate functions, you pass all of them into another function (again, capitals, but you get it), which has parameters named like `A_o_C`, which is entirely non-descriptive and very hard to keep track of when mixed in with `C_c`, `S_C_c`, etc.

Don't make your code look arcane and hard to read - nobody likes it and neither will future you.

After looking at your code, it would appear that `Amount_of_Characters` just returns a random integer between 1 and 9, `Character_chooser` generates a list of n random characters from some string, `Special_Character_chooser` does the exact same thing (except that they both modify another global). And `Number_chooser` does the same again.

Functions that have global side-effects are almost always a design mistake. Instead of manipulating a global variable, just return what the function is supposed to produce.

Your `Assembler` finally proceeds to shuffle the order of the randomly chosen sequences - but since they were already random, that's pointless. It seems to expect that variables like `Char_amt` have been modified by the previous functions, but in fact they are not declared as `global`, so they don't have the correct values. If they did, the `Assembler` seems to select a number of characters randomly from the shuffled random strings.

So, in the end, all your script does is:

- generate a string of length n
- each character of the string is randomly chosen from one of three collections of characters (English letters, numbers and some special characters) with equal odds

Therefore, this script does the exact same thing (once you get yours to work):

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters, digits


def generate_pass(n):
    chars = ['~!@#$%^&*()_', ascii_letters, digits]
    return ''.join([
        random.choice(chars[random.randint(0, 2)]) for _ in range(n)
    ])


print(generate_pass(10))
```

Everything else in your script is just moving stuff around and naming it. And applying random functions to something repeatedly doesn't necessarily make it more random. If you think the random library in Python somehow isn't random enough, you can find better libraries, but for the purpose of generating passwords, that would be pointless.

And by the way: this is assuming you actually want about equal measures of numbers, letters and special characters in your password, otherwise it could be even shorter:

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters, digits


def generate_pass(n):
    chars = '~!@#$%^&*()_' + ascii_letters + digits
    return ''.join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(n)])


print(generate_pass(10))
```

Comment: This makes total sense, and after taking a closer look with the breakpoints, I figured out that the shuffle was nonsense, along with other lines of code. Also, I do think the python random library is random enough, I was just unaware of writing unnecessary lines of code. Thank you for the tips about the capitalization, that will make me conscious of my grammar for programming, and make it readable. You're great, thank you very much, Grismar!

Comment: By the way, i have completed my code, and it works currently, in 3.7.4, I didn't want to abandon this mini project I've spent 2 1/2 hours on, but I didn't change any confusing variables, because i was about done debugging. Here's the GitHub link if you'd like to see the working version, thanks!-> https://github.com/BhrzIsChilly/PasswordGeneration

Comment: You're welcome - and thanks for taking criticism well, I realise it can come across as a bit harsh, glad you got things to work. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies mainly in the Assembler

**Error 1: Total_char, S_Character_amt, Character_amt, Nums_amt**

Run this:

```
def Assembler(A_o_C, C_c, S_C_c, N_c, Total_char, S_Char_amt, Char_amt, Num_amt, Pword):    
one = random.shuffle(C_c)
two = random.shuffle(S_C_c)
three = random.shuffle(N_c)
print(Total_char)
for i in range(Total_char):
    chooser = random.randint(1, 3)
    if i + 1 <= Char_amt:
        if chooser == 1:
            temp_num = random.randint(0, len(Numbers)-1)
            Pword += Numbers[temp_num]
            two.pop(temp_num)
            print("A")
    if i + 1 <= S_Char_amt + Char_amt and i + 1 > Char_amt:
        if chooser == 1:
            temp_num = random.randint(0, len(Special_Characters))
            Pword += Special_Characters[temp_num]
            two.pop(temp_num)
            print("B")
    if i + 1 > S_Char_amt + Char_amt:
        if chooser == 1:
            temp_num = random.randint(0, len(three))
            Pword += three[temp_num]
            two.pop(temp_num)
            print("C")
print(Pword)
return(Pword)
```

You will notice your Total_Char is always 0 and so the for loop was never executed. This is because of your Total_characters was defined to be 0 in the very first place

```
Nums_amt = 0
S_Character_amt = 0
Character_amt = 0
Total_characters = Nums_amt + S_Character_amt + Character_amt # 0+0+0
```

After which print all your other amts:

```
print(Total_characters) #0
print(S_Character_amt)  #0
print(Character_amt)    #0
print(Nums_amt)         #0
```

So in essence an example run of what your were doing was

Assembler(6,['l', 'Z', 'w', 'e', 'O', 'K', 't'] , ['#', '%', '#', '(', '*', '$', '^', ')'], ['3', '2', '3', '8'], 0, 0, 0, 0, "")

**Error 2: Shuffle**

random.shuffle() shuffles list item in place and returns None thus one, two and three are all None Types

random.shuffle(C_c) itself is sufficient and you can replace all the one in assembler back with C_c . Likewise for both two and three

**Error 3: Loop condition**

What does your loop index have to do with the length of your character array? You should probably look at just length of your arrays. If there is already nothing in the list skip.

Comment: Thank you Jackson, i've noticed these problems after looking through the code with breakpoints, and reverse engineering, you're spot on about the assembler being a big problem. I've really taken quite a bit of the arguments out of the assembler and re-arranged them. yet, Grismar pointed out that my code already randomized the characters, and there was no need for me to shuffle the list even further. Thank you very much for your feedback, it is much appreciated!